# Spotlight index not available to Alfred or Raycast

Tags: spotlight, alfred

M1 Pro MacBook Pro running MacOS Ventura 13.4

Neither Alfred nor Raycast's file search extension show any results when I search for files that I know exist (indeed, they show no files at all). The same searches in Spotlight work fine, so it seems like the Spotlight index is ok; it just seems like Alfred and Raycast can't *access* the Spotlight index.

Both apps can find applications ok.

Tried:

- re-indexing Spotlight
- removing Alfred and Raycast from Accessibility and Full Disk Access permissions, then re-adding them

This is a relatively new behaviour. I can't pinpoint exactly when it started, but it definitely wasn't a problem a few weeks ago. Both Alfred and Raycast file searches work fine on my 2020 iMac 27", also running 13.4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is embarrassing... *after* trying the things mentioned above, power cycling my Mac made everything work fine!

Comment: Better to report your embarrassing success than to have people trying to diagnose your problem. :)